# Why does "material_index" return zeros?

Tags: python, mesh, materials

I am new to `bpy` and I am wondering why the values `material_index` returns are all zeros.

This is the code I am using:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
    obj.select = True    
    material_ids = set()
    if obj.data is not None and hasattr(obj.data, "polygons"):
        for polygon in obj.data.polygons:
            material_ids.add(polygon.material_index)
```

`material_ids` is a set that only contains `0`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: polygon.material_index indicates the material to use for this polygon. If your object has only 1 material, all polygons will have the same/first material which index is zero. material_index is considered to be the index in the object material list (not in the overall material list).

Comment: and for that matter,also  if the mesh object is created for an object with  no materials (0 is the default material index value for a face). To be consise it is the index of `obj.material_slots` Suggest create a test object that has more than one material applied to more than one face.   Re code: See no need to select all with operator, or set active object for this.  For all meshes in `scene = bpy.context.scene` ie  the set : `meshes = set(o.data for o in scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH')`   Then for each mesh in meshes, `material_ids = set(f.material_index for f in mesh.polygons)`

Answer (score 0):

The number 'zero' is just a zero based enumerator (eg: 0th,1st,2nd...etc) for the material used on your polygon.

*I think*, that the enumerator order corresponds to it's position in the (Materials?) editor scroll box.

If you want to see '1'. Create a new material, select your object or a face of it and "Assign" (Button) the object to the second Material in the list. Re-run your script.

..oh, also "set" only contains unique values. So if all your polgons use material '0' there will only be one entry.